# What is a conforming implementation of std::regex_search's complexity using the iterator interface?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, std

Although the c++ standard doesn't seem to explicitly guarantee or prohibit it, certain implementations of std::regex_search appear to traverse the entire input regardless of where search success is found. (A minimal working example is many, many lines of code so please bear with me).

Consider a custom, conforming BidirectionalIterator class (call it FileContentsIter) that reads its input from a FILE*, appropriately caches what it reads so that the decrement operator works correctly, and compares equal to a default-constructed instance in the case where the file reaches EOF. Also assume normal copy and assignment semantics.

Now consider the use case where one wants to search for a sequence matching a particular regular expression using this custom iterator class. Suppose the input file contains: "abcdefghijk..." and the regex is simply "c".

Given a call to:

```
std::regex exp("c");
std::match_results<BidirIt,Alloc> results;
FileContentsIter in(someFile);
bool found = std::regex_search(in, FileContentsIter(), results, exp);
```

`found` should return true, match[0] should contain (in,FileContentsIter()) and match[1] should contain an iterator range spanning the "c".

This works correctly and is not in dispute. My question is centered around the complexity on conforming implementations (here LLVM). Profiling the 'increment' operator on `in` tells me that the entire file was read even though the regular expression was matched on the 3rd character.

Digging deeper into LLVM's implementation, I see the code:

```
template <class _BidirectionalIterator, class _CharT, class _Traits>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
bool
regex_search(_BidirectionalIterator __first, _BidirectionalIterator __last,
             const basic_regex<_CharT, _Traits>& __e,
             regex_constants::match_flag_type __flags = regex_constants::match_default)
{
    basic_string<_CharT> __s(__first, __last);
    match_results<const _CharT*> __mc;
    return __e.__search(__s.data(), __s.data() + __s.size(), __mc, __flags);
}
```

Notice the:

```
basic_string<_CharT> __s(__first, __last);
```

Which basically just means that the implementation shoves the entire input into a std::string and searches it. It is easy to see how this can be very bad in the case of multi-megabyte or gigabyte files that need to be incrementally searched for content (say in the case of a lexer).

This was surprising to me.

So to my question: is this behavior a function of the standard that I am missing or simply the "easy" implementation? Although unless someone answers that LLVM is actually nonconforming, I guess it really doesn't matter as I would need to use a different regular expression library (or refactor my code) so that reasonable incremental behavior is guaranteed.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The standard says nothing, so this is pure QoI.

Comment: Although I don't have the latest draft, this is my read as well. So the question is: should it contain language to address this? Seems reasonable to have: `vector<char> foo; regex_search(foo.begin(), foo.end(),...);` which will also make an unnecessary copy.

Comment: I believe your example exhibits undefined behavior, as `FileContentsIter()` cannot be decremented and thus does not satisfy requirements of a bidirectional iterator. `std::regex_search` has the right to traverse the range backwards, if it so chooses.

Comment: `regex_search` implementation you show is not the one you call - it doesn't take `match_results` parameter. What does the overload that takes one do? Does it still copy to string, search there, then reconstruct `match_results<YourIterator>` from `match_results<char*>` by playing with offsets?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, good point. You are correct regarding the default constructed FileContentsIter(). I was just trying to come up with a well defined problem statement without a huge MWE.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I did use the non-match_results version in the problem statement (which obviously does simply copy the input into a string). The iterator version of match_results does not overtly copy the results but still traverses the entire input range multiple times (this is were the custom iterator came from---to try and figure out why it was behaving so badly)

Comment: The vector version above `vector<char> foo; regex_search(foo.begin(), foo.end(),...);` is a better example.